# Noninvertible scalings of congruences may yield extraneous roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What modular arithmetic theorem is being ignored here?

1. Suppose $4x\equiv 6 \pmod {18} $
   Then $2x\equiv 3 \pmod 9$
   Then $6x\equiv 9 \pmod 9$
   Then $6x\equiv 0 \pmod 9$
   Then $x\equiv 0 \pmod 9$
   Then $x=9k$

vs.

1. Suppose $4x\equiv 6 \pmod {18}$
   Then $2x\equiv 3 \pmod 9$
   Then $2x\equiv 12 \pmod 9$
   Then $x\equiv 6 \pmod 9$
   Then $x = 9k+6$

Comment: In (i): $\;6x=0\pmod 9\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\implies x=0\pmod 9\;$ . For example, $\;6\cdot 3=0\pmod 9\;$ but $\;3\neq 0\pmod 9\;$

Comment: No theorem is ignored, but there is a "non sequitur" in 1.

Answer (score 2):

$6x\equiv 0\pmod 9$ does not imply $x\equiv 0\pmod 9$. Because $6$ and $9$ are not coprime. What you do get by dividing out one $3$ is that $2x\equiv 0\pmod 3$, though - but you knew that already.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you applied a *noninvertible* transformation to the equation, i.e. scaling by $\,3,\,$ which is not reversible because $\,3\,$ is *noninvertible* mod $\,9.\,$ Such noninvertible transformations may introduce $\rm\color{#c00}{extraneous}$ roots. In detail we have $\!\bmod 9\!:\ 2x\equiv 3\,\Rightarrow\, 6x\equiv 9\equiv 0,\,$ and $\,6x\equiv 0\!\iff\! 9\mid 6x\!\iff\! 3\mid 2x\!$ $\iff\! 3\mid x\!\iff\! x\equiv \color{#c00}{0,3},6\pmod{\! 9},\,$ but notice that $\,x\equiv \color{#c00}{0,3}\,$ are $\rm\color{#c00}{not}$ roots of $\,2x\equiv 3\pmod{\! 9},\,$ even though they are roots of $\,6x\equiv 9.$

But if we scale by an invertible $\,a\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) $\,b\,x\equiv c\,\smash[t]{\underset{\color{#c00}{\  \times\ a^{-1}}}{\color{#c00}{\Longleftarrow}}\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{\times\ a}\Longrightarrow}} \ ab\,x\equiv ac,\,$ since the direction $\,(\color{#c00}{\Longleftarrow})$ follows by multiplying the RHS by $\,\color{#c00}{a^{-1}}.\,$ So the LHS and RHS congruences have exactly the same set of roots. Hence no extraneous roots are introduced by scaling by an *invertible* element, i.e. the scaled congruence is *equivalent* to the original congruence.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3956055/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3266937/242).

Answer (score 1):

In $1$ the step from $6x\equiv 0$ (mod $9$) to $x\equiv 9$ (mod $9$) is invalid. The conclusion should be $2x\equiv 0$ (mod $3$), because the modulus is divisible by $3$ and then $x\equiv 0$ (mod $3$), because $(2,3)=1$. Or equivalently go all the way in one step because $(6,9)=3$ and if you want to divide by $6$ you must divide the modulus by $(6,9)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the multiplication law of modulus arithmetic. For all $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,n$ integers, $ a_1 a_2 \equiv b_1 b_2 \pmod n.\,$