# Extraneous solutions of congruences due to noninvertible scalings

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

To solve $\,26x\equiv 6\pmod{\!110},\,$ note $\,\gcd(26,110)=2\,$ so there are $\,2\,$ solutions.

Next, $\ 104x\equiv 24\pmod{\!110}\ $ follows by scaling the above by $\,4.$

i.e. $\,\ \ \ \ \ {-}6x\equiv 24\pmod{\!110}$

Hence $\ \ \ \ \,x\equiv -4\pmod{\!55}\ $ by dividing prior by $\,6$.

What is the final answer?

Comment: Can you please comment a little bit on your approaches? For me it's hard to see where you get your equations from.

Comment: It's also not clear what these are modulo with respect to. Are the parentheticals your modulus, e.g. are you trying to solve $26x \equiv 6 \pmod{110}$?

Comment: I corrected a sign error and reformatted to clarify the method.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\,x\equiv -4\pmod{\!55}\iff x\equiv 51, 106\pmod{\!110},\,$ so those are the sought $2$ solutions.

However you got lucky. The method you used will generally introduce *extraneous* solutions because you scaled by a number $(4)$ this is *noninvertible* $\bmod{110}$. To remedy that in general you need to test which of the derived *possible* solutions are *actual* solutions. This is not needed when we scale by invertibles since that yields equivalent congruences, i.e. the congruences are connected by $(\!\!\iff\!\!)$ arrows, vs. $(\Rightarrow)$.

For example if we do the same problem mod $220$ and scale by $8$ we deduce that any solution again satisfies $\,x\equiv -4\pmod{\!55},\,$ but only two of those $4$ possible solutions are actually solutions, viz. $\,x\equiv 51\pmod{\!110}\iff x\equiv 51,\,161\pmod{\!220}$.

You can avoid such problems by cancelling $\,2 =\gcd(26,110)\,$ at the *start* (vs. *end*), as in the general solution method explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410059/242).

Another handy way to solve such congruences is to use the [fractional extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242), which is closely related to the method that you (implicitly) employed.

Answer (score 0):

You could first solve $13x\equiv 3\mod 110$ by the extended Euclidean algorithm which is possible since $gcd(13,110)=1$ and then multiply the congruence by $2$ giving a solution of the original congruence.

Answer (score 0):

$26x \equiv 6 \pmod{110} \iff 110 | (26x - 6) \iff $ 
$55 | (13x - 3) \iff 13x \equiv 3 \pmod{55}.$

$55 = (4)13 + 3.$ 
$13 = 4(3) + 1.$

Therefore, 
$1 = 13 - 4[55 - 4(13)] = 17(13) - 4(55)$

Therefore, $17 \times 13 \equiv 1 \pmod{55}.$

Therefore, $3 \times (17 \times 13) \equiv 3 \equiv 13 x \pmod{55}.$

Therefore, $x \equiv 51 \pmod{55}.$

Therefore $55 | \{(13[51]) - 3\}$.

Therefore $110 | \{(26[51]) - 6\}$.

Therefore $\{26[51]\} \equiv 6 \pmod{110}.$

Therefore $x \equiv 51 \pmod{110}.$

Comment: I don't understand the part of "Therefore".

Comment: @Y.xin I am using the term "therefore" to indicate that the current line is implied by the previous line.  Is there a specific line in my answer that you are confused about?  If so, which line?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid scaling by a factor that is not comprime to the modulo; you may create/miss solutions.

From $26x \equiv 6 \pmod {110}$, we can divide everything by $2$ to reach $13 x \equiv 3 \pmod {55}$.

Now scaling by $4$ is valid, since $4$ and $55$ are coprime. We have:

$$12 \equiv 52 x \equiv -3 x \pmod {55}$$

Dividing both sides by $-3$, which is also coprime with $55$:

$$x \equiv -4 \pmod {55}$$

which is the solution you somehow managed to arrive at, despite the questionable method.

Comment: Dividing is not defined in modular arithmetic

Comment: @Mathsexplorer Multiplying the inverse is, hence the emphasis on *comprimality*.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. After rescaling it to $$13x \equiv 3 \pmod{55}$$, you can simply find the modular inverse of $13$ mod $55$, which in this case is $17$(Denoted by $13^{-1}$, and also note that it exists as 13 and 55 are coprime). Multiplying both sides by $17$ you get $$13 \times 13^{-1} x \equiv 3 \times 13^{-1} \pmod {55} $$  $$13 \times 17x \equiv x \equiv 3 \times 17 \pmod {55} $$  $$x \equiv 51 \pmod {55} $$